# How to get each value of same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have some tag with same class , i want get each their value and append it to a div how to do it

```
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>

for (i=1;i<$(".adr").length;i++) {
    $("#test").append($(".adr").html() + "</br>");
}
```

the result :

location1

location1

location1

location1

it seems did apppend 4 times first class, how to get 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 ?

Comment: `$("#test").append($(".adr").eq(i).html()...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `each` in jquery to get text of all `adr` class . Do not `append` line by line as it takes more execution time.Try to append as a whole, Hope this helps

```js
var str=''
$('.adr').each(function(e){
     str+=$(this).text()+ "<br>"
})
$("#test").html(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>
<div id =test></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#test').append($('.adr').clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
 <p class="adr">location2</p>
 <p class="adr">location3</p>
 <p class="adr">location4</p>

 <div id="test"></div>
```

You can append all matched elements with `.adr` using [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/). But only this would technically add the original elements and strip from it where it was previously situated in the DOM. So, [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) them to create a new copy of all elements and preserve it's previous state as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rows = $(".adr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    $("#test").append($(rows[i]).html() + "<br>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>
<div id =test></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$('.something') returns an array, so you need $('.something')[i] to get each item from the array.
You're calling three jQuery functions for every iteration of the loop - inefficient. Call them once each before the loop, assigning them to a variable, then use the variable instead of the jQuery calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` method. Secondly selecting `"#test"` and `".adr"` is a bad idea declare them as global variable and use them.

```js
let elms = $(".adr");
let test = $('#test');

elms.each(function(){
  test.append($(this).html() + "<br>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>

<div id="test">

</div>
```

#### Using `querySelectorAll()` and `map()`

```js
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('.adr')].map(x => x.innerHTML).join("<br>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>

<div id="test">

</div>
```